# Which is the Historical Khorasan

Tags: ancient-history, middle-east, iraq, sasanian-empire

The word Khorasan finds mention in many ancient texts pointing to a place in Middle east to Afghanistan . The question is what were the boundaries of the historical Khorasan which parts of the Middle East were included in Khorasan.

[Wikipedia says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Khorasan)  that Greater Khorasan, a historic region which lies mainly in modern-day Iran. It was previously known as Parthia; later, during the Sassanid era, it was renamed to Khorasan. But the etymological meaning of Khorasan (Persian) is "land of rising sun".

Thus wanted to know which regions of earth were included in Khorasan of  1500 years ago?

Comment: The [German Wikipedia](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chorasan) has a nice map in his article to Khorasan.

Comment: @knut you can answer with proof of the boundaries

Comment: Remember that (1) GPS is only a few decades old and (2) ancient borders were well defined only when coinciding with natural geographic features. Attempting to refine the requested border to a resolution of less than several miles is likely impossible, or simply a matter of opinion and thus debate. Voting to close as *Primarily Opinion Based*.